# 'net user <username> <password> /domain' seems to momentarily allow multiple good passwords

Tags: command-line, passwords, active-directory

So, let me preface this question by saying that I am not a domain administration expert. I'm a programmer who writes custom applications for the web.

My company wants to add a password reset feature from our Intranet login page. Our back end is ColdFusion 9 which has functionality in the language which allows me programmatic access to LDAP. In researching writing the code to make this password change feature work it occurred to me that it would be much easier to write code that would execute the following:

```
net user <username> <password> /domain
```

This of course, is done after all the customary old password checking and such. The command is executed as a user with the appropriate privileges to do so, and really it works just great.

However, I noticed a problem that after much troubleshooting with one of our server administrators we have been able to reproduce independent of any code that I've written.

**The problem is that once the net user command has been executed, both the OLD password and the NEW password are (for an undetermined interval of time) good passwords for the user account being changed.**

That's right. If we have a user *testuser* with a password of *welcome* and we run the following:

```
net user testuser welcome2 /domain
```

Then for an undetermined amount of time we are able to successfully log in to the domain using either  "welcome" or "welcome2" as a password. Now, after this undetermined interval of time the first password stops working and the new password is left as the only remaining working password.

This does NOT happen if we run the command directly on one of our two domain controllers, but it's not very feasible for me to have my web application execute that command directly on the PDC.

The only thing I can think of is that there is a time of propagation and that the password change is NOT immediate as it would be if run on the PDC itself.

So, I'm wondering... is this expected behavior? If I go the more difficult programmatic route of accessing the LDAP server directly and changing the user's password, am I likely to see a similar propagation issue?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/KB/128489

Comment: I largely didn't understand most of that KB article @STTR, but the last few paragraphs seem to be why you pointed to the article in the first place... I think. 

Does anyone else have anything germane to the subject of programmatically changing Active Directory passwords via the web?

Comment: I'm also being told by my server administrator that our company is NOT in a trust situation with two domains like this article talks about. I honestly didn't think we were, but he has now confirmed it for me. We only have one domain, but we have multiple domain controllers.

Comment: In the old MSDN Library articles that came to the Visual Studio has a lot of truth, which can be seen and adapt, as well as in this article. Replication mechanism similar interval of 15 minutes. Well, the link to the official source. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214678

Comment: Just now noticed your link to this other KB article. I'll read it now. Thanks again for all your assistance. :)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to solve your problem - Programming logon gui. I would say more, there are ready-paid solutions for the problem of forgotten passwords, which are exactly at the specified path.

There is a path number two - way system administration, when the department or working groups highlighted in the OU a particular person or in some cases the head of the unit is authorized to change passwords in the OU.

Your path is quite strange, because in the case of a local station in the logon gui costing system messages and intercept passwords can only be changed by a keyboard drivers, then, as in your case is not very clear as to how the password protection and the rejection of your service will impact directly on the whole enterprise.

In your decision you need to change your password in each domain, or run the synchronization force, which is not very good. Maybe not the mood on the workstation, which of the domains is the main workstation. This can be done that will receive the password with a specific domain controller in the first place.

Then agoritm will look like - reading ldap server with the highest prioretety, view primary dns on the workstation, browse by security log on the controller to determine where the station receives a password. After that, the particular controller can change the password. To reduce the necessary permissions, you can create the user and remove it from the Users group and the Domain Users and give permissions to read only in certain branches of the registry. To work with eventlogs better to use an intermediate database indexing for search Available immediately and also give unprivileged database user read-only access.

Or tolerate a situation from 15 to 0 minutes).

[ColdFusion 9 .NET Integration Service Installer](http://ftparmy.com/44202-coldfusion-9-net-integration-service-installer.html)

[SAML, SSO and ColdFusion](http://blog.tagworldwide.com/?p=19)

[SAML Service provider with coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084193/saml-service-provider-with-coldfusion)

[ColdFusion / SAML (Part 1)](http://dragonsaber.blogspot.ru/2009/09/coldfusion-saml-part-1.html)

[Active Directory as LDAP](http://www.selfadsi.org/deep-inside/ad-security-descriptors.htm)

[Understanding the AD FS 2.0 Proxy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/01/05/understanding-the-ad-fs-2-0-proxy.aspx)

[Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754361(v=ws.10).aspx)

[Automate Active Directory Migration Tool using Windows PowerShell](http://blog.powershell.no/2010/08/04/automate-active-directory-migration-tool-using-windows-powershell/)

[Migrating User Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784018(v=ws.10).aspx)

[A function to migrate a single user in the Active Directory Migration Tool, based on the sample script Invoke-ADMTUserMigration.ps1](http://poshcode.org/2048)

small offtop:
[Overview of Business Connectivity Services in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your more detailed response, @STTR. The reason for doing this at my company is because we have a group of non-corporate users whose workstations don't connect directly to our domain, but rather they just access our corporate Intranet via the web, and a domain account/password is required to login.

So the options for these users changing their password, or getting a password reset (for whatever reason - usually because an employee was let go) is to open a ticket with our help desk. 

My goal is to reduce the number of tickets to our help desk, by making this process more self-serve.

Comment: So, that's the background of *why* I'm taking this admittedly strange path. The workstations in question do not login to our domain, and so they can't change their password by conventional means.

It sounds like you're telling me that I either have to do this the slightly more complicated way (which I think I can do) or I have to accept that for anywhere from 0 to 15 minutes after a password change the old password might still be active while it propagates through the system.

Does that sound about right?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f97.html and http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:50152

Comment: Yes. I was already fully aware of these ColdFusion specific threads. I wasn't really asking you how to accomplish this in my given language. I was really just asking about the apparent delay when using the 'net user' command. In fact the last thing I asked was really a yes or no question, but instead you responded by updating your answer with a handful of links about migrating users, SAML, Power Shell migration tools, and ColdFusion, etc. It seems like you're trying to answer a question that I didn't ask. Thanks anyway for your effort. We've just decided to live with the delay in propagation.